# Pass a reference to a no-argument method in scala

Tags: scala

How can I pass a reference to a no-argument method reference in scala?

For example:

```
class Foo {
  def foo: String = computeSomethingAndReturnIt
}

object Foo extends App {
  def acceptSupplier(???) { doSomethingWithFooSupplier }
  val f = new Foo
  acceptSupplier(f.foo ???)
}
```

I know I can define `foo` to accept `Unit` by declaring `def foo()...` and this will work, but is there a way to pass `foo` and have it accept zero arguments as shown above in the code snippet?

Comment: Pass a reference to what? What is your desired signature of `acceptSupplier`? This seems unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a by-name argument:

```
def acceptSupplier(f: => String) { ... }
val f = new Foo
acceptSupplier(f.foo)
```

Comment: Note that this is also known as a [closure](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/automatic-closures.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or more explicitly:

```
def acceptSupplier(f: () => String) { ... }
val f = new Foo
acceptSupplier(f.foo _)
```

Comment: Heya, this was flagged as "low quality" probably because it's mostly code. Don't forget that newbies sometimes trawl the site... it'd be nice if you could explain a bit more :)